# Dealing with Complex Value Objects

Tags: architecture, object-oriented-design, enterprise-architecture, value-object

I am working with Martin Fowler's [definition](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) as a working base.

I have a class called `Condition` that I am having trouble properly classifying.

What makes me think this might be a value object:

1. A given `Condition` is only valid within a context of a single entity; `conditions` are never shared, nor addressed independently.
2. Its equality is based on its values; ie, a single entity should not have multiple of the same `condition`
3. They are never modified, only added or removed from a given entity.

However, they have some characteristics not typical of value objects as well:

1. Very complex logic and behavior.
2. Potentially, references to first-class entities make up its values.

---

Should I be treating my `Condition` class as an entity or a value?

If I do treat it as a value object, is it justified to place its data-access code in with its parent object's data-access code (`ParentEntityRepository`)? How should I deal with this class differently if it is a value object?

Comment: How large is the state of your `condition` object?

Comment: `Is it justified to place its data-access code in with its parent object's data-access code` -- That has less to do with whether or not it's a value object, and more to do with the fact that it's not a domain entity.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Unknown at compile time in terms of bytes. 3 fields + an ID field, which is only used for convenience

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the phrase "references to first-class entities make up its values"?

Comment: Also, is this C#?  Some other curly-brace language?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The function of this `Condition` class is to more or less act as a predicate for its parent. A condition could be `1stClassEntity2` is present within the current context.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, C#

Comment: Are you using inheritance or composition to relate this object to its "parent?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is related to its parent through composition. 'Parent.Conditions[]' Also, the `Condition` class it self uses compositional typing, one of its fields is `ConditionType` which defines its behavior.

Comment: OK.  Well, C# defines value objects mostly in terms of size and equality.  Fowler spends a great deal of time on equality, but C# treats strings as *values* for that purpose (even though they're reference types), and you can implement `IEquatable` on any object in C#.  Ultimately, I see value types in C as *small* data structures that intrinsically have value semantics in terms of equality and comparability.  The amount of logic doesn't matter. I suppose the question you have to ask yourself is, would you be comfortable declaring your `condition` object as a `struct` instead of a `class`?

Comment: Canonical examples of value types include a `Point` type containing X and Y coordinates, and a `Complex` type containing a real part and an imaginary part.

Comment: I don't really care about how C# treats it, what if change to Java? :) This is from an architectural point of view.

Comment: In Java everything is an object.  It's not going to matter in Java; in Java "value type" is just a couple of words from a class perspective, and not particularly interesting words.

Comment: But, for what it's worth, it doesn't sound like you're talking about a value type to me, in any programming language.  I don't think it really matters anyway; C# (and Java) have enough flexibility that you can define the semantics any way you see fit, without having to worry about whether or not your object fits some strict definition of "value type."

Comment: Do you have a need to compare `conditions` between entities?  For example, are you concerned with answering questions like which `conditions` are found in both entity X and Y?

Comment: Can you clarify "Potentially, references to first-class entities make up its values."  Are we to understand that these references would be part of the identity of the object?

Comment: @JimmyJames 1. Kind of, in that a request might ask, "Give me all the entities that have a condition with the value 'x' " (They don't want evaluate it by the id of the condition, but rather its value) 2. one of the fields of the `Condition` obj might be the ID of an entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description and the answer you gave in the comments, it sounds to me like condition is not a value object itself but that one of it's components is a value object.

I would only consider something a proper value object if all of it's state is evaluated in determining whether two instances are equal.  I would even go so far as to say that (e.g. in Java) you should not define an `equals` or `hashcode` for an object unless it is immutable and every piece of state is used as part of the implementation.  Under this rule, any object that has equals implemented is a value object.

If this works for your situation, it opens up the option of using [flyweights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) for these value objects within your `condition` objects.

Comment: Why not define equals for an entity to compare their Id(s)? You might have to separate instances that refer to the same entity

Comment: Are you saying implement an equals on the composite object?  I spent a lot of time twiddling around with equals() and what I learned is that universal equality is a useful concept but only in a narrow scope where you essentially don't ever care about about the object instance identity.  Outside of that, it starts to create more issues than i solves.  If you want to know if two objects refer to the same condition, I would do that directly i.e. `a.conditionId == b.conditionId`.  If you want me to elaborate, I can add to the answer.

Comment: I have started to come back to that conclusion as well.